# How can I prevent line break when reading a CSV text file with php?

Tags: php, file, csv, line-breaks

I have a CSV text file which contains serval entries of "books", each book is on one line (separator: line break), and each column is separated by a tabulation.

I'm reading the content the file with :

```
$books = file( "/path/to/file/mycsv.txt" , FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
```

That way I can go throuhg each element of the "books" array and read my individual "book" data.

The problem is that each book has a "description" column, which also contains line breaks. On import, this messes up the data, as it creates a line break before the end of an item.

How can I prevent that ?

Comment: Are you aware of http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your file include quotes around the `description` column, because if it does I believe [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) handles that situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PHP RTRIM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to trim the line breaks.
 or you can use a inbuilt feature  of php [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to fetch the file.